# How to remove multiple lines from CSV file in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a CSV file that has 5 lines at the top of the file that I want to remove using node.js. I then want to add my own header line that better matches the header I would use. I have no control of the original csv file so unable to to do this at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easiest using one of the following modules:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsv

or other that you find in:

- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/csv
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/tsv

(don't worry if it's CSV or TSV - just make sure that you use the correct delimiter which is comma in your case).

You might do it all manually parsing the file as text but using a module for that will be much less error prone.

```
(cat good-header.csv; tail -n +5 original-file.csv) > the-result.csv
```